# Allocating Right Amount of Rows Based On Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a NSMutableArray filled with NSMutableArray's. I would like to fill my table view up with the appropriate amount of rows, based on the size of a particular indexes array.

I currently have the array setup to grab the first element in the array, and the table then sets the amount of rows to that particular array's size. Ideally, i'd like to set the rows to the count of each element, of which most (arrays) have differing sizes.

Here is what I currently have:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        // Return the number of rows in the section.

        WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];
        NSMutableArray *blah = [[workoutManager workouts] objectAtIndex:0];

        return [blah count];
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I'd like to set the rows to the count of each element…" I'm having a really hard time parsing that. Are you saying you want to set the /number/ of rows to the count of each subarray? (You don't want to set the text in the row to be the subarray's count, do you?) Do you want to display all the workouts in the list (as sections, perhaps?) and the contents of each workout array grouped in each section?

Comment: Each individual sub-array are different sizes (or atleast have the potential to be). I'd like to know what I should return in the numberOfRowsInSection method to handle this without causing a crash.

Comment: Sounds like you want to be returning [[workoutManager workouts] count] in numberOfSectionsInTableView: and [[[workoutManager workouts] objectAtIndex:section] count] in numberOfRowsInSection:..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in following way:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];
        return [[workoutManager workouts] count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];
        NSMutableArray *blah = [[workoutManager workouts] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        return [blah count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
WorkoutManager *workoutManager = [WorkoutManager sharedInstance];
        NSMutableArray *blah = [[workoutManager workouts] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
YourObj *obj = [blah objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //Do further...
}
```